# pp - PAR Packager , Can't locate strict.pm

Tags: perl, executable, par, perl-packager

I have a perl script called master.pl and it contains following lines of code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
system("perl /proj/scripts/slave.pl");
```

I made binary executable of master.pl using command :

```
pp -b -B -o master master.pl
```

I copy this executable on other server (as pp command can not be available on other server so i made executable on my linux system ). When i run master it gives me error

***Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 .... ***

here the issue is slave.pl  contains use strict; and @INC shows path which are not valid on that server.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue ? I do not want to make executable of slave.pl . How can i make executable of master that when it calls
'''
system("perl /proj/scripts/slave.pl");
''' 
then it should have valid path in @INC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `system "perl …`. This executes the wrong Perl. Use [`$^X`](http://p3rl.org/var#$%5EX) instead.